# ansible failing with hidden error

Tags: ansible

Ansible is failing with failed=1 although no errors are showing up before.

How can I find out/debug what has caused the error?

```
ansible-playbook -u root -i 'apitest-centos7.xxxx.loc,' playbook_node.yml



PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Einfügen von $XXXXXXX_CONFIGURATION in bashrc] ****************************
ok: [apitest-centos7.xxxxxxx.loc]

TASK [install python-xml] ******************************************************
ok: [apitest-centos7.xxxxxxx.loc]

TASK [add xxxxxxx rpmrepo] ******************************************************
ok: [apitest-centos7.xxxxxxx.loc]

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [install software]  ********************************************************
ok: [apitest-centos7.xxxxxxx.loc] => (item=[u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx'])

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/xxxx/Projekte/testing/boxes/playbook_node.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
apitest-centos7.xxxx.loc : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: ...and of course it happens only when running all four tasks together, which you have checked before posting, by commenting out the other ones. ...and of course it's irrelevant what modules the tasks are calling, thus you saved the details...

Comment: ... sorry I don't get the point?!
Could you please elaborate on what I have done wrong?
I'm still pretty new to ansible.

Comment: The point is that you have done nothing. Just copy-pasted an error message and request a solution. What you posted requires spending some 30 seconds on the problem.

Comment: would it be helpful to post the playbook ? What else could I post?

Comment: We found the issue. Obviously a task was failing due to packages that were not designed for CentOs. Unfortunately this was not easy to discovery as the task was marked in green although it actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously a task was failing due to packages that were not designed for CentOs. Unfortunately this was not easy to discovery as the task was marked in green although it actually failed.

- [@Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131694/ansible-failing-with-hiden-error#comment71447733_42131694)